# Implicit Differentiation of a composite function

Tags: calculus

If $y=f(u)$ and $g(x)=u$, show that $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2y}{du^2}(\frac{du}{dx})^2+\frac{dy}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$$

I understand that (du/dy)*(dy/dx)=dy/dx. Would I simply implicitly differentiate from there on and substitute dy/dx for ((du/dy)*(dy/dx)).

Whilst doing this I got =d^2u/dy^2(dy/dx)+du/dy(d^2y/dx^2)

And then when plugging in the original form of dy/dx I got

=d^2u/dy^2((du/dy)*(dy/dx))+du/dy(d^2y/dx^2)

Am I making a conceptual/formatting/algebraic error?

Comment: Please show your efforts to solve this problem and let us know the exact issue you are facing while solving it. Without this the question will attract down votes and close votes.

Comment: Your equations are wrong (may be typo also). Note that $$\frac{dy} {dx} =\frac{dy} {du} \cdot\frac{du} {dx} $$ now differentiate again with respect to $x$ and use product rule.

Comment: Please do not use the edit function to vandalize a question (even your own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If y=f(u) and u=g(x)
 then $ y=f(g(x))
\\ 
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx} \\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})= \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}) \\ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dy}{du} \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{du}{dx} )+\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{du}) \\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dy}{du} \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d^2y}{du^2}\frac{du}{dx} \\\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=(\frac{du}{dx})^2\frac{d^2y}{du^2}+\frac{dy}{du} \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$y=f(u)$$
$$dy=f'(u)du$$
$$u=g(x)$$
$$du=g'(x)dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(u)g'(x)$$
Now manipulate the RHS until you can rewrite it in terms of the LHS
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f'(u)g''(x)+f''(u)g'(x)\frac{du}{dx}=f'(u)g''(x)+f''(u)(g'(x))^2$$
We know this because $\frac{du}{dx}=g'(x)$
$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=g''(x)$$
$$\frac{dy}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=f'(u)g''(x)$$

Thus going back to the original equation,

$$\frac{d^2y}{du^2}(\frac{du}{dx})^2+\frac{dy}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$$
$$=f''(x)(g'(x))^2+f'(u)g''(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have the chain rule
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now differentiate this and use the product rule
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(  \frac{dy}{dx}\right) &=& \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}  \right) \\
&=& \color{red}{\frac{d}{dx}}\left( \frac{dy}{du} \right)\frac{du}{dx}  + \frac{dy}{du}\frac{d}{dx}\left(  \frac{du}{dx}\right) \\
&=& \frac{du}{dx} \color{red}{\frac{du}{dx}}\color{red}{\frac{d}{du}}\left( \frac{dy}{du} \right)  + \frac{dy}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}  \\
&=&\left(  \frac{du}{dx}\right)^2  \frac{d^2y}{du^2}   + \frac{dy}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}  \\
\end{eqnarray*}